# How to create a PR to the repo that I forked? (not to the original repo)

Tags: git, github, fork, git-branch, pull-request

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6s1J9.png)

I'm trying to create a PR within the repo that I forked (not to the original repo). But whenever I push my code and create a PR, it gets created in the original repo.

Steps I took:

1. forked Bob's repo ( with master, dev, ABC, and DEF branches)
2. cloned to my local machine using myusername/repo.git (made sure git remote -v points to my forked repo)
3. git checkout -b newbranch
4. ( made some changes to a file )
5. git add .
6. git commit -m "test"
7. git push origin newbranch
8. created a PR on github page
9. The PR I created on step 8 shows up on Bob's repo as "Open" PR.

What am I doing wrong? How do I make the PR show up in my repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a PR, you are prompted for a base repository and branch, and a HEAD repository and branch.  It sounds like you've set the base repo to the upstream, when you want it to be your repo instead.

Comment: How to set the base repo to my own fork?